# Does scikit-learn use regularization by default?

Tags: logistic-regression, scikit-learn

I just fitted a logistic curve to some fake data. I made the data essentially a step function.

```
data = -------------++++++++++++++
```

But when I look at the fitted curve, the slope is very small. The function that best minimizes the cost function, assuming cross entropy, is the step function. Why does it not look like a step function? Is there some regularization, L1 or L2, done by default?

[image: Logistic regression using scikit-learn]

Answer (score 12):

Please take a look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). The first line shows the default parameters, which include `penalty='l2'` and `C=1.0`.

You actually cannot disable regularization completely, you can only regularize less... try setting `C=1e10` for example.

Comment: You can now (as of version 0.21.0) pass `penalty='none'`.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id15

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is regularization by default. It appears to be L2 regularization with a constant of 1.

I played around with this and found out that L2 regularization with a constant of 1 gives me a fit that looks exactly like what sci-kit learn gives me without specifying regularization.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression    
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
```

is the same as

```
model = LogisticRegression(penalty="l2", C=1)
model.fit(X, y)
```

When I chose `C=10000`, I got something that looked a lot more like step function.

Comment: Just following up with a little more detail. sebastianspiegel correctly identified the defaults that are still in the documentation, at least as of version 1.2.1: If values aren't specified, scikit-learn still uses [L2 regularization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression), with C set to 1.0.